# What's the rationale for closely spaced standard LVL sizes?

Tags: structural-engineering, composite, wood

Generally LVLs in the US seem to conform to heights that were historically used for solid lumber. e.g., 5 1/2" is the height of a nominal 2x6. This makes sense because presumably LVLs had easier adoption this way.

However there are a few sizes which don't follow this pattern and also are pretty close to others - specifically I'm thinking of 9 1/2 vs 9 1/4 and 11 7/8 vs 11 1/4. Especially with the first pair which differ very little, what's the reason for this?

Here's a table of common sizes from https://webstructural.com/beam-designer.html:

```
Name            Grade   Width   Height  Moment (ft-lbs) Shear (lbs)
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  5 1/2"  2125            1830
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  7 1/4"  3555            2410

Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  9 1/4"  5600            3075        *
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  9 1/2"  5885            3160        *

Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  11 1/4" 8070            3740        **
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  11 7/8" 8925            3950        **

Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  14"     12130           4655
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  16"     15555           5320
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  18"     19375           5985
Microllam LVL   2.0E    1 3/4"  20"     23580           6650
```

Comment: 11 7/8 is near enough 300mm which is a standard length for modular construction, except in one country that uses different weird units like inches, and then doesn't  even have "2x6 timber" that actually *measures* 2 inches by 6 inches!.